# How is my firewall making all websites look like a login page

Tags: security, firewall

In the morning this question came across my mind. You would notice my poor knowledge on firewalls.
My office installed a new firewall. I am provided a new username and a password. And here we have a login interface. I've searched browser's cookies, HTTP headers and everything, But I cannot figure out where is this login interface hosted. All I can see is www.google.com in address bar of the browser. Whichever site i tried to access, (without having logged in through the firewall) I found this kind of URL `www.google.com/abcd/ww/..`

Previously we had a known firewall... And  t was obvious through the URL `https://10.66.28.5:4100/wgcgi.cgi` So I knew whats the technology behind that.

But this new One is troubling me. I cannot even guess how this one works. Could You please explain?

Comment: Are you the administrator of this network? Can you tell us what the brand/model of the device is? And is it really a firewall, or is it a combination firewall/router or perhaps do you mean a proxy server?

Comment: No, I'm a web developer. Previously there was watchguard xtm proxy has installed. But I haven't got a chance to learn about this new one.

Comment: As a programer, I'm puzzled, where could be the Firewall login interface hosting?

Comment: Ask your network administrator.

Comment: I wish i could. :) 
But he is in the head office. Our area administrator doesn't seem to know much about this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP isn't the administrator of the network.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for anyone but the network administrator to answer this conclusively, since you won't be able to obtain the necessary information from anyone else.

Comment: @shan: Put in a call/raise a ticket with your help desk - that's your and their job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the new 'firewall' is doing more than just being a firewall.  Until you log in it is intercepting and directly answering all web requests with a page of its choosing so that all websites look like they are the login page.

Many internet cafe's and hotels wifi hotspots operate like this, so you can connect to their network for free but not receive internet until you are authorised.

As for general info about firewalls try [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))

A place to start looking for info on how your new system works try

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal (thanks tombull89 for jogging my memory on the name of this).  This is exactly what I think is on your network and causing all websites to be the login page.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041682/setting-up-a-login-page-for-wireless-hotspot as it sounds like your system is doing something similar.

As for actually inspecting what the system is, before you login try doing what this page says to view the http headers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome and google some of the phrases contained in the header that look to be different to normal websites.

Comment: "all websites look like they are the login page" Exactly!

Comment: how can I know more about this framework?

Comment: @shan, check out "captive portals". This is the name for the sort of setup you have there.

Comment: captive portals! can they hide server headers?